# What is the difference between Start Debugging and Attach to Process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7, worker-process

My project loads significantly faster when I attach it to my w3wp.exe IIS worker process, than when I "Start Debugging".

However, the same worker process seems to be processing the same amount of modules/DLLs (w3wp.exe) whether I "Start Debugging" or "Attach to Process".

Why is attaching to a process so much quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Start Debugging" launches a new instance of the executable with the debugger attached right from the beginning, so the overhead of all the needed debugger calls is incurred from launch, whereas "Attach to Process" attaches to a already running process, so until then your process was running without any additional overhead caused by debugging.

Comment: There's no good cause for using abbreviations like "w/o" in answers, @RudolfsBundulis. Welcome to the site!

Comment: So, when you choose "Attach to Process" you're attaching a debugger to the last good build of your project?

Comment: Ok, will take that into account. I guess since this is the first time, i'm forgiven.

Comment: @William - no, it attaches you to an already running process. From what I understand you are running IIS which I'm not too familiar about but I guess when you attach you just attach to a worker instance already spawned by IIS but when you start debugging you launch a fresh new worker instance. But to be exact we need to know what exactly are you building - dll module for the worker, another process,...?

Comment: Rudolfs, it seems to be re-building the whole project after even a minute change in code. Then reloading symbols for around 100 different DLLs generated by the rebuild, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 0):

The code without debugging performs much for faster. When you attach the process the application is already started, pool is started, so you do not perform some heavy operations in debug mode, for example Application_OnStart event and some others.